# Saving attachments from current email to a derived folder.

Tags: vba, outlook, save, attachment

I'm looking for a starting point here, so no code to post I'm afraid !

I would like (if possible) to be able to open an email in Outlook (in the normal way, from the front-end), and then click a button to run a macro, which will extract the attachments from this email and save them to a directory path (derived from the subject).

Sound do-able ?

Any pointers, links code snippets welcome !

Comment: Unfortunately not familiar enough with the Outlook VBA object and event model to coach you; however, I use a lot of VBA with Access and Excel and what you're after is absolutely doable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got as far as the saving to local folder and deleting from message. I haven't worked out buttons yet, but I'm sure it's not the hardest thing in the world...

So I would check out the VBA documentation on [Attachment Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175152.aspx), specifically the one on `SaveAsFile`, as it has a full example that I used to test things out. The two methods available are the exact ones you need:

```
SaveAsFile
```

and

```
Delete
```

But since VBA makes nothing simple, using those two lines requires 15 others.

Also there is a REALLY great site called [outlookcode.com](http://www.outlookcode.com/). The site admin is a VBA/Outlook wizard and she will personally answer your questions if they sit on the forums for a more than a day (not a guarantee, just my experience). The site is full of sources and other people's code, etc.

Here is what I wrote to try out what you had in mind, based on the sample from MSDN which I added the delete method, making it a one click save/delete:

```
Sub getAttatchment()
    Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments

    Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
    If Not TypeName(myInspector) = "Nothing" Then
        If TypeName(myInspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
            Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem
            Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
            If myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName = "" Then
                Set myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName = myAttachments.Item(1).FileName
            End If
                myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") _ 
                & "\My Documents\" & myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName
                myAttachments.Item(1).Delete
        Else
            MsgBox "The item is of the wrong type."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Be aware that the original sample has a dialog box to ask the user if they are sure they want to save as it will overwrite any files with the same name. I deleted it to simplify the code a bit.

Comment: Works - cheers !

On my (Windows XP SP3, Outlook 2007) system I had to change your code to include 'HOMEDIR' as well though.

myAttachments.item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEDRIVE") & "\" & Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\docs\" & myAttachments.item(1).DisplayName

Comment: unfortunately this seems to create a runtime error in some case. I believe this may be due to the fact that the attachment has been embedded rather or in cases that the attachment does not already have a filename

Comment: That's interesting, as I've recently noticed that embedded logos and the like have the attachment icon, which irritates me to no end.  I've added a possible fix (haven't tested).  Since the `DisplayName` property is read/write and `FileName` property is read-only, I'm assuming `FileName` can't be blank (though may be less than friendly to look at), so if `DisplayName` is empty it defaults to `FileName`. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This subroutine will save all attachments found in a user specified Outlook folder to a user specified directory on the file system. It also updates each message with a link to the purged files.

It contains extra comments to help highlight how the .Delete method will shrink Attachment containers dynamically (search for "~~" in the comments).

This subroutine is only tested on Outlook 2010.

```
' ------------------------------------------------------------.
' Requires the following references:
'    Visual Basic for Applications
'    Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library
'    OLE Automation
'    Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
'    Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation
' ------------------------------------------------------------.

Public Sub SaveOLFolderAttachments()

 ' Ask the user to select a file system folder for saving the attachments
 Dim oShell As Object
 Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 Dim fsSaveFolder As Object
 Set fsSaveFolder = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please Select a Save Folder:", 1)
 If fsSaveFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 ' Note:  BrowseForFolder doesn't add a trailing slash

 ' Ask the user to select an Outlook folder to process
 Dim olPurgeFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Set olPurgeFolder = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
 If olPurgeFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

 ' Iteration variables
 Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim att As Outlook.attachment
 Dim sSavePathFS As String
 Dim sDelAtts as String

 For Each msg In olPurgeFolder.Items

   sDelAtts = ""

   ' We check each msg for attachments as opposed to using .Restrict("[Attachment] > 0")
   ' on our olPurgeFolder.Items collection.  The collection returned by the Restrict method
   ' will be dynamically updated each time we remove an attachment.  Each update will
   ' reindex the collection.  As a result, it does not provide a reliable means for iteration.
   ' This is why the For Each style loops will not work. ~~
   If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

     ' This While loop is controlled via the .Delete method which
     ' will decrement msg.Attachments.Count by one each time. ~~
     While msg.Attachments.Count > 0

       ' Save the attachment to the file system
       sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder.Self.Path & "\" & msg.Attachments(1).FileName
       msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS

       ' Build up a string to denote the file system save path(s)
       ' Format the string according to the msg.BodyFormat.
       If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            sDelAtts = sDelAtts & vbCrLf & "<file://" & sSavePathFS & ">"
       Else
            sDelAtts = sDelAtts & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & sSavePathFS & "'>" & sSavePathFS & "</a>"
       End If

       ' Delete the current attachment.  We use a "1" here instead of an "i"
       ' because the .Delete method will shrink the size of the msg.Attachments
       ' collection for us.  Use some well placed Debug.Print statements to see
       ' the behavior. ~~
       msg.Attachments(1).Delete

      Wend

     ' Modify the body of the msg to show the file system location of
     ' the deleted attachments.
     If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
        msg.Body = msg.Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts
     Else
        msg.HTMLBody = msg.HTMLBody & "<p></p><p>" & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts & "</p>"
     End If

      ' Save the edits to the msg.  If you forget this line, the attachments will not be deleted.  ~~
     msg.Save

    End If

  Next

End Sub
```